# What financial impact does opening up a book have?

Tags: finance

Say you're a writer and you've wrote a lot of books. You release them all for no cost as download on your website (and some shops), but you also sell printed copies. You keep copyrights, but everyone can download the digital version for free.

And now you decide it is better to make the book open. That involves:

- everyone can redistribute it, not only the shops you authorized
- everyone can use it to make money without asking you
- everyone can change it or remix and distribute or sell the derivate

How does that impact the financials?

To be clear, in both cases the book can be downloaded without costs involved, I want to know if there is such impact if price is no issue. Also it would be good if you have examples or even better studies to substantiate your answer.

Comment: So you're not selling the physical books directly; there's a bookshop vender?

Comment: @HDE226868: Probably.

Answer (score 2):

I see a major key issue here: *Everyone can redistribute it*. That, mixed with *Everyone can use it to make money without asking you* really looks like fancy wording for taking your work and selling it for free. Please don't do this.

> How does that impact the financials?

Well, if people can sell it for free, it's like asking...

- Would you like a free delicious apple?
- or Would you like an expensive delicious apple?

Clearly, everyone will ask of it for free.

I'm no economist or anything, but your sales and revenue will decrease ridiculously, as you'll only get money from people loyal to getting something directly from authors, people who feel free is "sketchy", and hardcover sales in your approved stores.

[For example: The significant lack of income from Kindle Unlimited has seriously affected authors.](http://the-digital-reader.com/2014/12/01/author-discontent-grows-kindle-unlimited-enters-fifth-month/) I understand it's not the same as opening the book, but it demonstrates the lack of income that can affect people.

Comment: Please substantiate your answer with actual studies. (In fact some authors have had success with making their books freely distributable and requesting donations. But it's difficult to pull off if you don't already have a fan base.)

Comment: @Gilles Adding something right now :)

Comment: @Gilles - just be aware - [not everything needs sources](http://meta.opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/84/what-should-our-reference-policy-be).

Comment: It is not the choice between a gratis apple (book) and a expensive one, it is the choice between a gratis one and a gratis open source one.